# XML to SQL Server Code Issue

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an issue with understanding how to query values from XML nodes within SQL server.  I have a very large and complicated XML file that I'm trying to read,   I've found several sites that offer advice for specific cases, and while some work in simpler versions of my problem, none work with the file itself.

The following code is some code that recreates a part of the XML file for me to use to learn the syntax, and it works:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML


set @XML = '
                                    <creditscores>
                                        <creditscore>
                                            <score class="10">571</score>
                                            <reasons>
                                                <code>506</code>
                                                <code>115</code>
                                                <code>116</code>
                                                <code>104</code>
                                            </reasons>
                                        </creditscore>
                                        <creditscore>
                                            <score class="2">586</score>
                                            <reasons>
                                                <code>105</code>
                                                <code>302</code>
                                                <code>112</code>
                                                <code>104</code>
                                            </reasons>
                                        </creditscore>
                                    </creditscores>
'

select @XML
;

--Credit Score Reason Codes
select
i.x.value('text()[1]', 'int') as [Code]
from @XML.nodes('/creditscores/creditscore/reasons/code') as i(x)
```

All good so far, I get an output of eight rows, but now I'm wanting to capture the two 'score's in a separate column, and also catch the 'class' of the score.

My output should be three columns:

```
class, score, code;
10,    571,   506;
10,    571,   115;
10,    571,   116;
10,    571,   104;
2,     586,   105;
2,     586,   302;
2,     586,   112;
2,     586,   104;
```

Thanks in advance, I've not found an example of someone asking for anything similar in my searches.

Edit:  Added expected output

Edit 2: I have now worked out how to get the 'class' but I cant get it at the same time as the Code, only the Score.  I used this query:

```
--Credit Scores
select
i.scores.value('@class', 'int') as Class,
i.scores.value('text()[1]', 'int') as Score
from @XML.nodes('/creditscores/creditscore/score') as i(scores)
```

That gives me the following output:

```
Class,  Score;
10,     571;
2,      586;
```

Comment: Could you show what you expected output would be for the data you have please?

Comment: Put it in your question; comments can't contain formatted text, so saying "imagine this data in 3 columns" doesn't help. That just looks like you've pivoted your data (and tehre are plenty of dynamic pivot examples on SO :) )

Comment: Added to question, also part solved the 'Class' issue so added my progress there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add another layer in your `FROM` to the other node. You can do this by using `CROSS APPLY`. According that `reasons` is also at the same layer as `score`, then one way would be:

```
SELECT i.scores.value('@class', 'int') as Class,
       i.scores.value('text()[1]', 'int') as Score,
       s.code.value('text()[1]','int') AS Code
FROM @XML.nodes('/creditscores/creditscore/score') AS i(scores)
     CROSS APPLY i.scores.nodes('../reasons/code') AS s(code);
```

Personally, however, I would wruite the query this way:

```
SELECT cs.score.value('@class', 'int') as Class,
       cs.score.value('text()[1]', 'int') as Score,
       cr.code.value('text()[1]','int') AS Code
FROM @XML.nodes('/creditscores/creditscore') AS i(creditscore)
     CROSS APPLY i.creditscore.nodes('score') AS cs(score)
     CROSS APPLY i.creditscore.nodes('reasons/code') AS cr(code);
```

Comment: Hi Larnu, if there is always just one `<score>` below `<creditscore>` there's no need for another `CROSS APPLY`. The repeating element is `<creditscore>` and you will get the class with `.value('(score/@class)[1]','int')`, while the content is returned with `.value('(score/text())[1]','int')`. It is quite some extra load to create a derived table just to return one single row... Good answer anyway, +1 from my side

Comment: Worked a treat; I went with the second one as it explains the logic better and can be used when I add even more complex issues to the XML.  Essentially as long as i start with the lowest level of node, and then cross apply to higher levels that contain the data I need, I can join anything in the file.